# If $\sum (a_n)^2$ converges and $\sum (b_n)^2$ converges, does $\sum (a_n)(b_n)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces

> If $\sum (a_n)^2$ converges and $\sum (b_n)^2$ converges, does $\sum (a_n)(b_n)$ converge?

Could someone help me to solve this or at least give me a hint?, I have tried using Cauchy's criterion, the Dirichlet test for convergence, etc, but I can´t prove it.Honestly I don´t know where to start. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: using cauchy will require knowing either 1) $l^2$ is an inner product space or 2) monotone convergence for real numbers, which seems slightly complicated for such a simple problem (not to say I don't approve!)

Comment: Vote to close.  The OP has not returned for 2 years.

Comment: @cats how is monotone convergence complicated for any problem? Without there's no comparison test which is the simplest of the convergence tests

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Start from here :$$(|a_n|-|b_n|)^2=a_n^2+b_n^2-2|a_nb_n|\ge 0$$

$$\implies |a_nb_n|\le \frac{1}{2}(a_n^2+b_n^2)$$By comparison test, $\sum a_nb_n$ is absolutely convergent , hence convergent.

Comment: But how do I know that $(a_n)(b_n)\ge0$ so that I can apply the comparison test? Can I really try sequences just like numbers? thanks

Comment: Easy enough fix, but you might need to specify that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positive or else take the absolute value and then apply the above result to show it absolutely converges and therefore convereges

Comment: Thanks, it was so easy but I didn't see it...

Comment: would this work for complex numbers?

Comment: @Nimish absolute convergence implies convergence

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch that assumes absolute convergence is what is being used here. It *should* be because conditional convergence is bad, but still.