# Simple convergence problem: If $\sum a_n^2$ and $\sum b_n^2$ are convergent, then $\sum a_n b_n$ is also convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

This, as the title says should be very simple, I am terribly stuck.

If $\sum a_n^2$ and $\sum b_n^2$ are convergent, how do I prove that $\sum a_n b_n$ is also convergent??

Comment: Consider $\ell^2$, the space of real sequences which finite serie of the squares, this is a Hilbert Space. What would be a (standard) scalar product on such a space ? Then a famous inequality should somes to your mind.

Comment: @nicomezi I think AM-GM is even simpler than C-S here

Comment: Please [make your title more informative](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144). At the moment people browsing or searching won't know what your question is about

Comment: thanks..it would be great if I knew what a Hilbert Space is..am new into all this..but thanks..

Comment: Then use @MaximilianJanisch 's hint

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279707/if-sum-a-n2-converges-and-sum-b-n2-converges-does-sum-a-nb-n

Comment: thanks this guy up here..

Comment: (this question already existed)
[original](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279707/if-sum-a-n2-converges-and-sum-b-n2-converges-does-sum-a-nb-n)